# Ansible WinRM The maximum number of concurrent operations for this user has been exceeded

Tags: ansible, winrm

We are using Ansible playbooks to automate long running scripts on many systems within our network, Some of those systems are Windows 10 while the others are Windows 7. The long running operations are launched using the [async](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_async.html) mechanism and the ansible module [async_status](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/async_status_module.html#async-status-module) is used to poll the results of the tasks every 30 seconds.

```
- name: Long running operation
    win_command:
      cmd: cmd
      _raw_params: python long_running_script.py
    async: 2140000
    poll: 0
    register: async_sleeper
  - name: Status poll
    async_status: jid="{{ async_sleeper.ansible_job_id }}"
    register: job_result
    until: job_result.finished
    retries: 100001
    delay: 30
```

The windows 10 server have the following default configuration for WinRM:

```
MaxConcurrentOperations = 4294967295
MaxConcurrentOperationsPerUser = 1500
```

Every ~12.5 hours or so, the playbook errors out with "maximum number of concurrent operations for this user has been exceeded" and this corresponds neatly to 1500 / 30 (our poll interval)
But clearly async_status is not a concurrent operation. It is supposed to be a short-lived check whether the process is still running and should exit after. So at any given point the number of concurrent processes must not exceed 2. The Task manager on the client machine does not show any lingering processes. So what is happening? Does ConcurrentOperation refer to Count of operations and not really of concurrency? We know we can increase the [quota](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winrm/quotas) but we do not want to do that on production systems without getting to the root of this problem.

It would help to know:

1. What do Concurrent Operation really mean?
2. What is the industry best practice to overcome this problem?
3. What has changed in Windows 10 that this error is not found in the other version of the OS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ran some experiments and it turns out that the value for MaxConcurrentOperationsPerUser  is indeed a counter and does not have to be "Concurrent"
This behavior is different between Windows 7 where it behaves like what its name implies and Windows 10 where it is a counter. 
So if we set the variable to 30, and have a long running operation that we poll the status every 30 seconds - then the operation will error in 15 minutes.

This issue may either be addressed in the future or fixed but leaving it here for anyone else who might face it.